# Setting up elasticsearch on windows os?

Tags: json, curl, elasticsearch, sense, curl-commandline

I have gone through tutorials of ES but not able to configure it on my system.

I install ES,cURL,JSON view and is working fine. I am not able to install sense plugin for chrome as it says moved to marvel and from there no link to download.

I tried:

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/test_idx_1x"
```

And index get created. Then i tried :

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/test_idx_1x/test_mapping_1x/_mapping" -d '{
  "test_mapping_1x": {
    "properties": {
      "my_attachments": {
        "type": "attachment"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

It's throwing `NullPointerException`.

What I need to do to run ES for flat file, Could anyone please guide me with simple steps?

ERROR:

```
2014-03-20 12:01:02,517][DEBUG][action.admin.indices.mapping.put] [Madelyne Pryor] failed to put mappings on indices [[test_idx_1x]], type [test_mapp
ng_1x]
ava.lang.NullPointerException
       at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentFactory.xContent(XContentFactory.java:117)
       at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentHelper.convertToMap(XContentHelper.java:113)
       at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentHelper.convertToMap(XContentHelper.java:101)
       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.parseCompressed(DocumentMapperParser.java:177)
       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.parse(MapperService.java:387)
       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.parse(MapperService.java:377)
       at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataMappingService$5.execute(MetaDataMappingService.java:540)
       at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$UpdateTask.run(InternalClusterService.java:308)
       at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor
java:134)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
```

Comment: Can you post full error thrown??

Comment: Have you installed mapper-attachment plugin??

Answer (score 0):

Also add the header with your command:

```
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

If still doesn't work, then wrap your json with double quotes instead of single. For example:

```
-d "{\"test_mapping_1x\" :\"...\"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when trying to do a mapping from Git Bash shell on Windows.

The same command run natively in Windows cmd.exe worked fine (sadly).